# How to resize (width / height) web page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

How to `resize` (width / height) web page using javascript ?

Normally we use `mouse scroll wheel + Ctrl` on browser to `resize` web page.

I want to know how can i using javascript to `resize` web page as same as use `mouse scroll wheel + Ctrl`

I search for javascript function and stackoverflow question to do this but not found.

please advice me, Best regards.

Comment: What you talk about is not **resizing**, but **zoom**, which is different thing.

Comment: @ Yeldar Kurmangaliyev ---- i have to change from resize to zoom-in/zoom-out ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with CSS:

```
body {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* Moz-browsers */
    zoom: 0.8; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
    zoom: 80%; /* Webkit browsers */
}
```

CSS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omerblink/ff3L9hh5/

And with jQuery you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').css({
    'zoom': '50%'
  });
});
```

jQuery Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omerblink/ff3L9hh5/1/

Let me know if you need more assistance :)

Comment: can i zoom to fit windows browser ?

Comment: Why you want to do that ... If you are doing this to fit in the mobile browser then just use meta scaling in the <head>

Comment: i want to tried to do with `zoom` first. ^_^ please advice me ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can zoom the webpage using the javascript code below

HTML code:

```
<body id="container">
  <button type="" onclick="zoomIn()">Zoom In</button>
  <button type="" onclick="zoomOut()">Zoom Out</button>
</body>
```

Javascript code:

```
 function zoomIn()
        {
            var Page = document.getElementById('container');
            var zoom = parseInt(Page.style.zoom) + 10 +'%'
            Page.style.zoom = zoom;
            return false;
        }

        function zoomOut()
        {
            var Page = document.getElementById('container');
            var zoom = parseInt(Page.style.zoom) - 10 +'%'
            Page.style.zoom = zoom;
            return false;
        }
```